# Rebel pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

What do you call a word with the same spelling and the same meaning, but different pronunciation if it is a verb or a noun?  It doesn’t fit the definition of homonym, homophone,  or homograph.

Take “rebel” as an example. As a noun it’s pronounced one way and differently as a verb, but it has the same spelling and same root meaning.

Also, are there any other examples of this occurrence?

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicate with [a term for words that change pronunciation with part of speech.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239164/a-term-for-words-that-change-pronunciation-with-part-of-speech)

English has many word pairs that are spelt alike but pronounced differently, according to whether the word is being used as a noun or as a verb. I believe the term to be **initial-stress derivation**.

> Initial-stress derivation is a phonological process in English, wherein stress is moved to the first syllable of any of several dozen verbs when they become nouns or adjectives. (This is an example of a *suprafix*.) It is gradually becoming more standardized in some English dialects but is not present in all, and the list of affected words differs from area to area, and whether a word is used metaphorically or not. At least 170 verb-noun (or adjective) pairs exist.

Here is a list of [some examples](http://www.businessenglishresources.com/31-2/teachers-section/mini-lessons/pronunciation-lessons-pronunciation-changes-in-words-that-are-both-nouns-and-verbs/):

> **NOUN         VERB**
>
> CONduct    conDUCT
>
> ATTribute  attrIBute
>
> COMbat comBAT
>
> CONflict   conFLICT
>
> CONtest    conTEST
>
> CONtract   conTRACT
>
> DEcrease   deCREASE
>
> EScort esCORT
>
> IMpact imPACT
>
> INcrease   inCREASE
>
> INsult inSULT
>
> OBject obJECT
>
> PERmit perMIT
>
> PREsent    preSENT
>
> PROceed    proCEED
>
> PROgress   proGRESS
>
> PROject    proJECT
>
> REbel  reBEL
>
> REfill reFILL
>
> REfund reFUND
>
> REject reJECT
>
> REpeat rePEAT
>
> SUBject    subJECT
>
> SUSpect    susPECT